# read javascript source

Tags: javascript

In my html file I put as

```
<script src='http://otherdomain/file.js' ></script>
```

When I run my webpage, that other javascript creates some html content using `docuemnt.write` command.

How can I dynamically read that dynamic html using the javascript on my html page?

Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could overwrite `document.write` to just *store* the input and not write it. When you're done, restore it to normal behavior:

```
<script>
var outputBuffer = "", old = document.write;
document.write = function(buffer) {
    outputBuffer += buffer; // store the contents for later use
};
</script>
<script src="http://otherdomain.com/file.js"></script>
<script>
document.write = old; // restore document.write to normal behavior
document.write(outputBuffer); // if you want to write it out
</script>
```

A working demo: http://jsbin.com/isuqi

Comment: hi.. yes. it worked.. Thank you very much for the help.. It is actually a HACK right ?  
what is the security for our dynamic scripts. when we got to put on other sites ? 
if they can read the dynamic script what our js creating they can utilize it..  how can we stop it ??

Comment: For all practical purposes, you cannot both make data available and prevent people from using it.

Answer (score 2):

If you know where the other JavaScript writes its content it's easy to read it. If for example everything is written into the following div-container:

```
<div id="updatable"></div>
```

Then you could retrieve it by calling something like `document.getElementById("updatable").childNodes` or `document.getElementById("updatable").innerHTML`

Answer (score 1):

If you just need to play around with the actual elements on the constructed page then you can use javascript to modify the DOM. (W3Schools has a [tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/HTMLDOM/default.asp))

For example, you can get a reference to a tag with id `"myID"` as follows:

```
myTag = document.getElementById("myID");

myTag.style = <new style>;
  etc.
```

---

If you want the raw HTML source of your new page you can call `innerHTML`:

```
myHTML = document.documentElement.innerHTML;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need a solution that works on any browser but just for analyzing you might get what you want from mutation events.

http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-eventgroupings-mutationevents

Have a look at the DOMNodeInserted event. When you register a handler at the top document than you are called when ever someone is adding elements to your tree. For every action you might want there is an event type suitable. I'm not sure to which extent it is supported but might be worth trying

Answer (score 0):

if you just want to do it for debugging purpose, then use IE web developer tool or firebug to view the generated source code. :)